# Wix/Burn UI Customisation

Tags: user-interface, wix, installation, burn

Im trying to create a Burn installer/bundle which looks like the License Hyperlink in that it has the Sidebar image on the install screens, but with an RTF license instead.
How can i do this? I have tried with my own UI customisations but the installer fails to run so very confused. 
is there an equivalent of the HyperlinkSidebarLicense i dont know about?: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/

Comment: Maybe you could get some inspiration from this project: http://classicwixburntheme.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen thanks for the link, i borrowed his XML/WXL theme and adjusted for my purposes, i think i was probably going round it the wrong way, trying to utilise a "license.rtf" as opposed to using a localisable string in the Hyperlink License UI.